# Whats the most efficient way to make repeated use of a class in PHP?

Tags: php, performance, micro-optimization

I have a basic MVC setup with helper classes containing utility methods, several of these are likely to be used when loading a view, in both the view itself, the controller and sometimes, but not often, the models. I use autoloading to find the helper files I need, so the class is only ever included once, then, in theory the file shouldn't get searched/included again, that way I don't have to put include statements in the script and (i believe) the file isn't loaded unless the class is used.

My question is what's likely to be the most efficient way to make calls to these helper classes? Should I make all methods in a given helper static, or maybe use a singleton pattern for the helpers or should I just create a new instance wherever it's used (e.g. an instance in the view an instance in the controller...) ?

thanks for your input

Comment: This should probably be tagged `micro-optimisation`. You should go ahead and write your code, then take a look at what slows it down if anything at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (i believe) the file isn't loaded unless the class is used.

Correct. That's how autoloading works.

> My question is what's likely to be the most efficient way to make calls to these helper classes?

Efficient, well, what's efficient? Maybe using C/C++ and compiling the stuff. Anyway, let's try:

> Should I make all methods in a given helper static,

No.

> or maybe use a singleton pattern for the helpers

No.

> or should I just create a new instance wherever it's used (e.g. an instance in the view an instance in the controller...) ?

Yes. If you only use them from time to time, that's very efficient because you can make use of anything as you see fit.

In case you use the *same* object more often, pass it around, inject it into other functions as it's needed.

This way you will get the most benefit from autoloading.

---

Helper object that can have multiple helper you can pass around even, will autoload on first access (lazy loading):

```
class Helper
{
    private $helpers = array();
    public function __get($name)
    {
        $name = strtolower($name);
        if(!isset($this->helpers[$name]))
        {
            $classname = ucfirst($name).'Helper';
            $this->helpers[$name] = new $classname;
        }
        return $this->helpers[$name];
    }
}

class Controller
{
    private $helper;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->helper = new Helper();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        $ingredients = $this->helper->something->getIngredientsList();
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: My controller runs first, I could extract() all the helpers i use there to pass them to the view. Is it likely to be more efficient than creating a new SomethingHelper() in the view/any other controllers that get used? It would probably mean having to check to see if the helper variable was already defined and then create an instance if not. I don't know if this adds much overhead.

Comment: Create a helper class that is part of your controller you can assign helpers to. See also the magic methods classes offer in PHP, you can load the helper the first time a property is accessed: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php, http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Comment: @user984830: I added a small example, it's just a quick mock, but might already have all you need. Keep things simple, that's efficient.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I'd like the helper directly accessible to Models and Views too though, not stored in a controller property. Would there be anything wrong with adapting your helper class to work as Helpers::something->getIngredientsList() ? I know garbage collection wouldn't hit this so is the tradeoff vs re-instantiating the helpers favorable?

Comment: Why should models have control- and view- helper? Anyway, why don't you give the view a property so it know to which controller it belongs and therefore can access controller helpers as well? Or you could just inject helpers of the current controller when the view is executed. If you need a global registry for your helpers, just use the standard one that ships with PHP: `$GLOBALS`, e.g. `$GLOBALS['Helpers']->something->getIngredientsList();`. The static classname is very similar to this. But it's easier to change it later on, because you will need to refactor away from global state anyway.